# MVVM - using closures to bind a ViewModel with a DataSource: capture list needed?

Tags: ios, swift, closures, weak-references, retain-cycle

I have a `viewController` keeping a (strong) reference to its `viewModel`

```
lazy private var viewModel: ListViewModel = {
   return ListViewModel()
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   initViewModel()
}

private func initViewModel() {
   viewModel.onModelChange = { [weak self] () in
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
         self?.tableView.reloadData()
      }
   }

   viewModel.fetchData()
}
```

Apple´s Swift documentation days that:

> A strong reference cycle can also occur if you assign a closure to a property of a class instance, and the body of that closure captures the instance.

This `viewController` holds a `viewController` which holds a closure that captures the `viewController`, so I understand a strong reference cycle could occur.

These are the `viewModel`'s properties:

```
var onModelChange: (() -> Void)?

private var model: [MyModel] = [MyModel]() {
    didSet {
        self.onModelChange?()
    }
}
```

On the other hand, this `viewController` is the `root` one, so won´t be deallocated during the app's life. And I don´t explicitly *nilify* its `viewModel` property. So:

- **Question 1**: is there actually a risk of a strong reference cycle happening? Should I provide a capture list to the closure anyway?
- **Question 2**: I set the capture list to be `[weak self]` but, since it seems the `viewController` and its `viewModel` would be deallocated same time, I guess I should have defined `[unowned self]` instead? Does it hurt to define `[weak self]` in case of doubt?

Let's think that now the `viewController` is one that is pushed on top of the `root` one, so it could be pop during the life of the app. The `viewController`'s `fetchData()` method is like this:

```
func fetchData() {
    dataSource.getData(completion: { (result, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            self.model = [MyModel]()
        } else {
            if let result = result {
                self.model = result
            } else {
                self.model = [MyModel]()
            }
        }
    })
}
```

where `dataSource` is a strong property and could get the data from either a local file (sync task) or to call a service (asyn task).

The `model` is also a property that is observed and calls the closure provided from the `viewController`

So:

- **Question 3**: in case the `dataSource` is getting the data from a local file. What happens then if the `viewController` is pop in the meanwhile? Would the `viewModel` still be alive until the `dataSource` finishes? In such case, is it correct to provide the `[weak self]` capture list in the closure?
- **Question 4**: in case the `dataSource` is performing an async network call, and the `viewController` is pop in the meanwhile, would be the same scenario than before? I mean, would the `viewModel` be still alive until the `dataSource` finishes?

**EDIT:** **Scenario/Question 5**

Now my `viewModel` asks also an object `UserSettingsManager` to get some other data:

```
func getUserSettings() {
    UserSettingsManager.getInfo { (result, error) in
        if error == nil {
            self.userData = result
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this `UserSettingsManager` is not a property of the `viewModel` as `dataSource` is, it is a class that only provides `static func`. Those `static func` are passed closures as `@escaping`, so I guess a strong reference cycle could also happen in this scenario, right? Or would this scenario be different from the previous ones? Which capture list would I need here (if any)?

Answer (score 0):

> Question 1: is there actually a risk of a strong reference cycle
>   happening? Should I provide a capture list to the closure anyway?

The strong reference cycle **will** happen. The question should be whether or not the strong reference cycle matters.  In this case probably not, but it would probably be a good idea to keep the weak reference anyway, just in case you move the controller in the future.  It's a small price to pay for future safety.

> Question 2: I set the capture list to be [weak self] but, since it
>   seems the viewController and its viewModel would be deallocated same
>   time, I guess I should have defined [unowned self] instead? Does it
>   hurt to define [weak self] in case of doubt?

`[unowned self]` implies that `self` will definitely exist when the closure is called.  Unless you are absolutely sure that's the case, you should stick with `[weak self]`. My preference is to always use `weak` as it's not to much extra effort to safely unwrap, and you avoid a crash if you somehow missed a case where `self` could be deallocated. If you use `self` many times in a closure it might be nice to unwrap it in a guard statement or move the code to a separate function.

> Question 3: in case the dataSource is getting the data from a local
>   file. What happens then if the viewController is pop in the meanwhile?
>   Would the viewModel still be alive until the dataSource finishes? In
>   such case, is it correct to provide the [weak self] capture list in
>   the closure?

In your example you have a strong reference to `self` in the closure, so you have a strong reference cycle which means the ViewController will never be deallocated.

Either way, if you grab the data synchronously, a tap to dismiss the view controller won't get to do it's work until after the fetch from the file and the code in the block is complete. Those would have to complete before the main thread becomes unblocked and the code to dismiss the controller can execute.

> Question 4: in case the dataSource is performing an async network
>   call, and the viewController is pop in the meanwhile, would be the
>   same scenario than before? I mean, would the viewModel be still alive
>   until the dataSource finishes?

If you made it a weak reference and dataSource was retained outside the controller so it outlives the controller, it is possible that `self` could be nil when the closure is called.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I have some more doubts regarding the 2 last questions:

- **Question 3 scenario**. Since `dataSource` is not keeping an explicit reference to the closure passed to its `getData` method, but it is `@escaping` such method, so yes, I guess there could be a strong reference cyle there also but between the `viewModel` and the `dataSource`, right?. So should I  have set the `[weak self]` capture list?

Comment: **Question 4 scenario**: being the `dataSource` performing an async network call, it would retain `viewModel` until the callback? Or could the `viewModel` be deallocated while the async task is in progress, and then `dataSource` could not find the `viewModel` (`self`) when it finishes and the closure is called? Should I have a `[weak self]` capture list also here then?

Comment: In both scearios 3 and 4, the `viewModel` keeps a strong reference to its `dataSource`, so could the `dataSource` actually putlive the `viewController`? Considering both cases, the `dataSource` performing an asyn file parsing and an async network call.